# How to communicate between concurrent sessions in PHP ans JS?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, concurrency, ipc

I have PHP server, in which I need to update client A about some client B action, at the moment it's done. How it is normally being accomplished ?

My current solution would be:

1. A leaves an open `$.ajax(...).done(function myCallBack(){...});` call for this.
2. when A is in `myCallBack(){...}` it issues another `$.ajax(...).done(function myCallBack(){...});`. This way the communication with server stays open for receiving new info anytime
3. the PHP would have to continually check for inter-session communication file to transfer data to/from two concurrent sessions

Leaving `$.ajax(...).done(function myCallBack(){...});` open (and spawning new ones all the time) is the way to do it ?

For inter-session communication - is there a way to signal events or something like that (instead of continuously monitoring some file [a waste of resources!]) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

Client ***A*** leaves an open `ajax` call: `$.ajax(...).done(function myCallBack(){...});`: on the PHP server side (session), ***A*** locks on a `semaphore` using `sem_acquire($semaphore_A)`, and waits.

Client ***B*** removes semaphore `$semaphore_A` using `sem_remove($semaphore_A)`, thus releasing ***A*** that returns to client JS callback `myCallBack()`.

Of-course, it's very simplistic, and I use [shared-memory (e.g. `shm_attach()`)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shm-attach.php) to exchange status and data between processes.

### For other developers stuck with this technique:

what took me so long to debug it, is the fact the I opened a session (`session_start()`) and didn't close it (`session_ write_ close()`) - which locked other processes and prevented any concurrency !

Answer (score 0):

Client A would send data to the server, Client B needs to poll the server to ask for changes. When there are changes Client B would get them on it's next poll.

Comment: yes, this is what I'm doing in my chat system... the clients check for new messages every 3 seconds

Comment: What do you say about leaving `$.ajax(...).done(function myCallBack(){...});` open (and spawning new ones all the time) is the way to do it ?

Comment: And how do I signal on the PHP server that session A sent data for session B ? I know I can continuously monitor, but isn't there more efficient way to do it ?